# Integrate WSO2 API Manager with third-party API Gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm interested in using only the Publisher and the Store. We have already many API gateways in place and also a dedicated OAuth Authorization Server.
The Publisher and the Store should be used basically as an API Portal where APIs are published and potential new consumers can self-register...

I understand that all necessary information is distributed within the WSO 2 API Manager ecosystem out-of-the-box. But could this behaviour be adjusted in the following way:

- When publishing an API it must be created on an external, third-party API Gateway. This gateway has it's own management API which must be triggered by the Publisher.
- When a new consumer registers to an API the external, third-party OAuth authorization server must be called in order to create the necessary OAuth information there so that the new consumer is known on the Authorization Server. Again, the Authorization Server has it's own management API which must be triggered by the Store.
- Is it possible to add custom fields in the Store which allows a consumer to enter additional information?

Any feedback is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on thrid party gateways, WSO2 API Manager does not support this at the moment.

But we do support incorporating a third party Key manager. You can plug a third-party OAuth provider to manage OAuth clients and access tokens. This is supported from API manager 1.9.0 onwards.

You may need to implement a key manager extention to incorporate  your OAuth Authorization Server. WSO2 API manager includes a key manager extention to 'Surf OAuth Authorization Server' by default.

You can find more details on configuring a thrid party Key manager at [1] and [2]

To answer your question on adding custom fields, yes, you can include custom fields by customizing the store with a sub theme [1] [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Extending+Key+Validation

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+a+new+API+Store+Theme

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+a+new+API+Store+Theme#AddinganewAPIStoreTheme-Writingasubthemeofthemaintheme